# Building where clause based upon parameters

Tags: postgresql, case, where

In PostgreSQL I am trying to build a where clause in a function that uses an inbound parameter to determine the contents of the IN

For example:

```
select fld1, count(fld1)
from xyz
where fld1 in (
    case $1
        when 1 then 'Value1'
        when 2 then 'Value2'
        when 3 then '''Value1'',''Value2'''
        when 4 then '''Value4'',''Value5'',''Value6'''
    else NULL
)
group by fld1
```

Value 1 works fine as does Value2, Values 3 and 4 fail not syntactically but no rows are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Your suggestion is bad practice

From the code given it looks like you want to

- supply a variable from your application `$1`
- depending on that supplied variable make sure column `fld1` is set to a specific set of values.
- **I like [the suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155500) of using simple `OR`** however, if your condition is complex and you want to maintain it that can get to be very messy. Here is *another* way.

Here was your code,

```
select fld1, count(fld1)
from xyz
where fld1 in (
    case $1
        when 1 then 'Value1'
        when 2 then 'Value2'
        when 3 then '''Value1'',''Value2'''
        when 4 then '''Value4'',''Value5'',''Value6'''
    else NULL
)
group by fld1
```

However, I would unroll this as a JOIN, and later spring it off into another table. Really `CASE` should likely never be used in a `WHERE` clause.

```
select fld1, count(fld1)
from xyz
join ( VALUES
  (1, ARRAY['Value1'])
  , (2, ARRAY['Value2'])
  , (3, ARRAY['Value1','Value2'])
  , (4, ARRAY['Value4','Value5','Value6'])
) AS cond(code,values)
  ON ( code = $1 AND fld1 = any(cond.values) )
group by fld1
```

From there you can even use CTE's which may make it faster, and it'll look more maintainable.

```
WITH cond(code,values) AS (VALUES
  (1, ARRAY['Value1'])
  , (2, ARRAY['Value2'])
  , (3, ARRAY['Value1','Value2'])
  , (4, ARRAY['Value4','Value5','Value6'])
)
select fld1, count(fld1)
from xyz
join cond ON ( code = $1 AND fld1 = any(cond.values) )
group by fld1
```

From the CTE, you can just as well make `cond(fld1,values)` its own table if it gets too bloody.

Comment: I slightly disagree on the **"bad practice"**. His intention is bad practice. His code is just **bad code** because it doesn't do what he was hoping to do. (*"Values 3 and 4 fail not syntactically but no rows are returned."*)

Answer (score 5):

The output of a `CASE` expression has to be a single value not a list of values.

The statement did not give a syntax error for cases 3 and 4 because  `'''Value1'',''Value2'''` is evaluated as a single string (which includes 4 quote characters and a comma): `'Value1','Value2'`

You could rewrite your condition using a `CASE` expression that evaluates to boolean, like this:

```
select fld1, count(*)
from xyz
where case $1
          when 1 then fld1 in ('Value1')
          when 2 then fld1 in ('Value2')
          when 3 then fld1 in ('Value1', 'Value2')
          when 4 then fld1 in ('Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6')
      end
group by fld1 ;
```

but I'd prefer to write it more more simply using `OR`:

```
select fld1, count(*)
from xyz
where ( $1 = 1 and fld1 in ('Value1')
     or $1 = 2 and fld1 in ('Value2')
     or $1 = 3 and fld1 in ('Value1', 'Value2')
     or $1 = 4 and fld1 in ('Value4', 'Value5', 'Value6')
      )
group by fld1 ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using arrays:

```
select fld1, count(fld1)
from xyz
where fld1 = any(
    case $1
        when 1 then array('Value1')
        when 2 then array('Value2')
        when 3 then array('Value1','Value2')
        when 4 then array('Value4','Value5','Value6')
        else NULL -- actually can be skipped as mentioned by ypercubeᵀᴹ
    end 
)
group by fld1;
```

if you execute `explain verbose select 1 in (1,2,3);` then you will see that the `in` operator translated to `... = any(...` internally:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                 QUERY PLAN                 ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)   ║
║   Output: (1 = ANY ('{1,2,3}'::integer[])) ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 4):

Since implementing the filter with the help of a virtual table is an option for you, you could also consider the classic one-to-many form instead of arrays:

```
values
  (1, 'Value1'),
  (2, 'Value2'),
  (3, 'Value1'),
  (3, 'Value2'),
  (4, 'Value4'),
  (4, 'Value5'),
  (4, 'Value6')
```

You can use it in a number of ways:

- join it conventionally:

  ```
  select
    xyz.fld1,
    count(xyz.fld1)
  from
    xyz
    inner join
    (
      values
        (1, 'Value1'),
        (2, 'Value2'),
        (3, 'Value1'),
        (3, 'Value2'),
        (4, 'Value4'),
        (4, 'Value5'),
        (4, 'Value6')
    ) as fltr (paramValue, fld1Value)
    on ($1, xyz.fld1) = (fltr.paramValue, fltr.fld1Value)
  ;
  ```
- use it as the right side of an IN predicate:

  ```
  select
    xyz.fld1,
    count(xyz.fld1)
  from
    xyz
  where
    ($1, xyz.fld1) in
    (
      values
        (1, 'Value1'),
        (2, 'Value2'),
        (3, 'Value1'),
        (3, 'Value2'),
        (4, 'Value4'),
        (4, 'Value5'),
        (4, 'Value6')
    )
  ;
  ```
- intersect it with each source row, checking the matches in an EXISTS predicate:

  ```
  select
    xyz.fld1,
    count(xyz.fld1)
  from
    xyz
  where
    exists
    (
      values
        ($1, xyz.fld1)
      intersect
      values
        (1, 'Value1'),
        (2, 'Value2'),
        (3, 'Value1'),
        (3, 'Value2'),
        (4, 'Value4'),
        (4, 'Value5'),
        (4, 'Value6')
    )
  ;
  ```